# How to use common request and response in soap asynctask throughout multiple activities android?

Tags: java, android, json, soap, android-asynctask

I am using Soap request and response using asynctask. I am sending json request and fetching the     response. But How to use this asynctask to perform request and response in common class. So that I    can use in multiple activites by passing request and fetch response. Please provide me solution. How to solve this?
So far I am doing like this. I wrote for single asynctask. But for another service call, I need to perform another asynctask. How to use this in common and perform.
I have commented in code for better understanding. Here is my code.

```
class A extend Activity{
    private String sessionId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.sortfilterclick);
      new CommonElement().execute();
  }
  class CommonElement extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      ProgressDialog dialog;

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          dialog = new ProgressDialog(CommonElement.this);
          dialog.show();
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
       try {
    // these are all common
           SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
           env.dotNet = false;
           env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
           env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
           HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.API_URL);
           sessionId = Utils.readPreferences(CommonElement.this,Constants.SESSION_ID, null);
           if (sessionId == null) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "login");
            request.addProperty("username", "Clothing");
            request.addProperty("apiKey", "Clothing");
            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
            Object result = env.getResponse();
            sessionId = result.toString();
            Utils.savePreferences(SortFilterPopupActivity.this,
                Constants.SESSION_ID, sessionId);
     }// till this it's common
    //here json reuest datas varies in json.put()...
     SoapObject requests = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "call");//these are common
    requests.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);//these are common
    requests.addProperty("resourcePath","sortap.Action"); //this will change for every property
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();// these will change 
    json.put("page", "1");
    json.put("limit", "10");
    json.put("name", sortName);
    json.put("order", sortOrder);
    json.put("id", "3");
    json.put("cate_id", "4");
    String params = json.toString();
    requests.addProperty("args", params);
    env.setOutputSoapObject(requests);
    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
    Object results = env.getResponse();
    //based on various request and response this varies.
    if (results.toString() != null) {
        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(results.toString());
        JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = object.getString("id");
            String productName = object.getString("product_name");
            String imageUrl = object.getString("image_url");
            int productPrice = object.getInt("price");
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  dialog.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain what you are asking again.